# Google checkout button doesn't work in nopcommerce

Tags: google-checkout, nopcommerce

I setted up google checkout payment method in nopcommerce and it appears on cart, but it doesn't work. I looked at html and find that form with id=form-googlecheckout doesn't appear on my page. Why it could heppened?

Also I am not sure in flow of google checkout. Will me clients be redirected to onecheckout page after process payment?

Thanks,
Yaroslav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the second question, the answer is no.

There is no automatic re-direct for the buyer after the Google Checkout transaction finishes. The buyer has to **click** on a provided link to navigate back to the seller's site.

You can programatically provide a link for the buyer to click and get back to your site after completing the order. Using the Checkout API you can change this URL for every order. See the continue_url paramenter:

https://developers.google.com/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_HTML_API_Parameter_Reference#tag_continue-shopping-url

Comment: ok I found answer on first question: `code` @using (Html.BeginRouteForm("Plugin.Payments.GoogleCheckout.SubmitButton", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "form-googlecheckout" })) `code` can't be inside other form :) Thank you.